# Ninja Form to Salesforce from curl it return nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, salesforce, ninja-forms

I am integrating ninja form to post data on Salesforce.

My Code is given below. I have applied ninja form hook and doing the code in WordPress theme functions.php file.

```
@$ch = curl_init();
    $form = [];

    if ($ch !== false) { 

    $form = [
        'oid'=> '*******',
        'retURL' => 'http://',
        'first_name'=> (!empty($first_name) ? trim($first_name) : ''),
        'last_name'=> (!empty($last_name) ? trim($last_name) : ''),
        'email'=> (!empty($email) ? trim($email) : ''),

    ];

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => "https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $form
    );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close ($ch);

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($server_output ); echo "</pre>";  // It returns nothing. Why ??

    }
```

Can anyone help me what is the issue with this code. Because when I do print_r it returns nothing.
And no data is going to salesforce.

Any Help will be appreciating.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to print the curl object, which has been closed. Try printing `$server_output`

Comment: @aynber empty response. nothing. I tried variable $server_output

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance nothing's wrong with your code. Assuming the org id is correct and you're looking in the right SF org (prod? sandbox? by the way - very good idea to redact it here).

1. Ask your Salesforce admin to examine the Lead object. What fields are required, what validation rules are there, maybe even triggers.
2. Try creating a Lead with identical data from SF UI, not your form
3. Try making same POST request in Postman, SoapUI or similar tool.

It might be that it's SF config issue. Maybe Web-to-Lead functionality isn't enabled in the target org. Or maybe the org is at 100% storage usage ;) You need to experiment bit more, ask SF admin/dev to help.